# Data validation in python

Tags: python

I want to create a program where the user must enter a primary colour, and if they don't they get an error message and have to try again. I'm new to data validation. What am I doing wrong?

```
primary_colour1 = 'red'
primary_colour2 = 'blue'
primary_colour3 = 'yellow'

while True: 
    colour1 = str(input("Please enter a primary colour: "))
    colour2 = str(input("Please enter a primary colour: "))

    try:
        colour1 = primary_colour1 or primary_colour2 or primary_colour3
        break

    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a primary colour only")
        print()


    if  colour1 and colour2 == primary_colour1 and primary_colour2:
        print("Mixing those colours gives purple")

    elif colour1 and colour2 == primary_colour2 and primary_colour3:
        print("Mixing these colours will give you green")

    elif colour1 and colour2 == primary_colour1 and primary_colour3:
        print("Mixing those colours will give you orange")
```

Comment: `colour1 = primary_colour1 or primary_colour2 or primary_colour3` This statement cannot possibly raise a ValueError.  Are you trying to check if `colour1` is **equal** to one of those?

Comment: That was what I was trying to do, yes!

Answer (score 1):

You have few issues with your code:

1. When you code reaches to the [`break`](https://www.coursera.org/tutorials/python-break) it exits the while loop and doesn't reach to the other parts of your code.
2. The following line will always set `colour1` to the first `True` value, meaning `colour1 = 'red'`

```
colour1 = primary_colour1 or primary_colour2 or primary_colour3
```

For example try and replace the conditions and see how it affects the value returned.

```
>>> 1 or 2
1
>>> 0 or 5
5
>>> 'A' or 'B'
'A'
```

3. In your code you are only trying to validate `colour1` and not `colour2`
4. Your `if` and `elif` conditions don't check what you meant:

for example,

```
    if  colour1 and colour2 == primary_colour1 and primary_colour2:
```

It checks that colour1 and primary_colour2 exists (not `''` or `None`, `False`...)

And it checks if `colour2 == primarycolour1`

** Another thing to mentions is that `input` returns a `string` so you don't need to convert it to string yourself.

You can change your code like so:

```
primary_colour1 = 'red'
primary_colour2 = 'blue'
primary_colour3 = 'yellow'

def get_color(out, *args):
    while True:
        colour = input(out)
        if colour in args:
            return colour
        else:
            print('Not a primary colour.\nPlease enter a primary colour only')

while True: 
    colour1 = get_color("Please enter a primary colour: ", primary_colour1, primary_colour2, primary_colour3)
    colour2 = get_color("Please enter a primary colour: ", primary_colour1, primary_colour2, primary_colour3)

    if  {colour1, colour2} == {primary_colour1, primary_colour2}:
        print("Mixing those colours gives purple")

    elif {colour1, colour2} == {primary_colour2, primary_colour3}:
        print("Mixing these colours will give you green")

    elif {colour1, colour2} == {primary_colour1, primary_colour3}:
        print("Mixing those colours will give you orange")
```

You can also use a `dict` of combinations to define all the possible combinations in advance:

```
combs = {frozenset(('red', 'blue')) : 'purple',
         frozenset(('blue', 'yellow')) : 'green',
         frozenset(('yellow', 'red')) : 'orange'}

primary_colours = set()
for comb in combs.keys():
    primary_colours.update(comb)

def get_color(out, colours):
    while True:
        colour = input(out)
        if colour in colours:
            return colour
        else:
            print('Not a primary colour.\nPlease enter a primary colour only')

while True: 
    colour1 = get_color("Please enter a primary colour: ", primary_colours)
    colour2 = get_color("Please enter a primary colour: ", primary_colours)

    try:
        print(f'Mixing those colours gives {combs[frozenset((colour1,colour2))]}')
    except:
        print('Comb not available')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a try-except for this purpose. Instead, simply verify if the input matches your criteria. Furthermore, it's more efficient to use lists. For instance, with a list like `['blue', 'red']`, you can easily check for the presence of `'red' and 'blue'` using the `in` keyword. This way, you don't have to account for every possible combination.

```
primary_colours = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']

while True: 
    colours = [
        input("Please enter a primary colour: ").lower(), #ignore upercases
        input("Please enter a primary colour: ").lower(),
    ]

    # Validate the colors
    if colours[0] not in primary_colours or colours[1] not in primary_colours:
        print("Please enter a primary colour only")
        continue  # Continue the loop to get valid colors you can also break

    # Check color combinations
    if ('red' in colours and 'blue' in colours) :
        print("Mixing those colours gives purple")

    elif ('yellow' in colours and 'blue' in colours):
        print("Mixing these colours will give you green")

    elif ('red' in colours and 'yellow' in colours):
        print("Mixing those colours will give you orange")
    break
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There is a lot for me to learn from this :) 
Just a question, the numbers in the if statement [0], [1]. are they referring to the different inputs in the colours variable?

Comment: [0] means the element 0 in the colours list (lists index start from 0)